# Error when creating a new document inside a new subcollection in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the v9 Web SDK.

I have a collection called 'transactions-in' which keeps a record of every transaction into a cardano wallet.

From time to time my server will send a transaction in response to each transaction in this collection (such as sending an nft or refunding ADA) and I want to add these transactions into a subcollection on the relevant transaction document, so the structure looks like this:

- collection: 'payments_in'
- document: document ID
- subcollection: 'related_transactions'
- document: newly created document reference

This is the code I have to get the right path to the newly created document ref and upload some test data into the firebase emulator:

```
  //1. Get current doc
  const currentDoc = doc(db, 'payments_in', transactionId);

  //2. Build refund database entry
  //2A. Get collection from database (will create one if doesn't exist)
  const newCollection = collection(currentDoc, 'related_transactions');

  //2B. Get a new document from database within new collection
  const newSubDoc = doc(newCollection);

  //2C. Upload entry to database
  await setDoc(newSubDoc, { test: 'test' });
```

When I log the path of newSubDoc I get this, so the path looks good (I think??): `payments_in/kXK5pimm29nRhU4CohA6/related_transactions/NL11eYmsB4M9vHw6PI8X`

However when I try to submit the entry using setDoc I get the following error message:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.1.1): Connection GRPC stream error. 
Code: 3 Message: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Document name "projects//databases/(default)/documents/payments_in/kXK5pimm29nRhU4CohA6/related_transactions/tLoCiHUJaA2uYhxt7drb" 
lacks a project id at index 9.
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the path in the error message, it is missing a project ID after `projects/`: `projects//databases/(default)/documents/payments_in/kXK5pimm29nRhU4CohA6/related_transactions/tLoCiHUJaA2uYhxt7drb`. You might want to double check how you initialize `db` and whether your Firebase configuration is complete.

Comment: ah yes, my dotenv config was no longer picking up the project id for some reason. thank you for your help, i find the firebase error messages pretty hard to parse (not a critcism of the product, which is really great, just something i need to study more).